# If Kuru kings called Dhritarashtra Vaichitraveerya and Janamejaya are mentioned in the Yajurveda, why is there no reference to the Mahabharata?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata

In the Kathaka Samhita of the Yajurveda, Dhritarashtra Vaichitraveerya is mentioned as a Kuru king and Janamejaya is mentioned in the Atharva Veda. Why don't we find any references to Yudhishthira or the Mahabharata war then?

Comment: Can you quote the verses and verse number too?

Comment: Even I haven't seen. But on wikipedia and according to other websites like this one https://bharatkalyan97.blogspot.com/2021/05/sri-brahma-refers-to-125-years.html it is mentioned that a Kuru king named Dhritarashtra, son of Vichitraveerya whose cattle was destroyed is mentioned in the Yajur Veda.

Comment: https://www.vyasaonline.com/encyclopedia/janamejaya/#:~:text=Janamejaya%20is%20mentioned%20as%20a,his%20descendants%20are%20called%20Tur.